# Tests with set_the_flash `[]` method not recognised

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, shoulda

I'm trying to have the value of my `flash` I call in the controller.

```
def upload
  ...
  flash[:error] = 'error'
  redirect_to :action => 'index'
end
```

To perform, I use `set_the_flash` with `shoulda` as below:

```
should 'be able to upload a file' do
  ...
  set_the_flash[:error].to('error')
end
```

But when I run this test, I have this error:

> NoMethodError: undefined method `[]' for #Shoulda::ActionController::Matchers::SetTheFlashMatcher

If I look at the doc, the method is present and the example it shows is quite the same as mine:

```
#   it { should set_the_flash[:alert].to("Password doesn't match") }
```

Comment: The example uses `rspec` syntax, are you using rspec?

Comment: ok, I realize that I just wanted to do this: `assert_equal flash[:error], 'error'`. But I still don't understand why what I wrote didn't worked.